# OSM - Nominatim - ERROR: Scripts must be run from build directory

Tags: openstreetmap, php, nominatim, centos

i'm trying to setup my own nominatim server in a CentOS 7 VirtualMachine. I'm using [this guide](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/appendix/Install-on-Centos-7/) which is followed [here](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Import-and-Update/) for data import.

This line gives me trouble when trying to import data:

```
./utils/setup.php --osm-file <_data_file_> --all
```

When executing the above command, the output says "ERROR: Scripts must be run from build directory.".

Which one would be the build directory?

I tried running from nominatim root directory, utils, and data, but no luck.

Comment: Please avoid crosspostings.

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer from [help.openstreetmap.org](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/62251/nominatim-setupphp-error-scripts-must-be-run-from-build-directory/62254).

The command was meant to be run from the "build" folder, that was it.

Comment: See also a bunch of Centos and SELinux issues and pull requests mentioned at e.g. https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/pull/937 .

Comment: Why is installing Nominatim so difficult? I still cant make it work. For each step in the installation manual there are ten missing.

Comment: If you want to write a document explaining what's missing, I'm sure that other people would find it useful - maybe something at the level of https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-16-04-2-lts/ ?

Comment: @SomeoneElse, I owe you. The page you pointed me at is absolutely perfect. Steps are correct, in order, and the overall result does work. Thank you very, very much.